# node.js: зачем использовать express?

Tags: node.js, безопасность, шаблонизаторы, jade

Прочитал массу статей, но так и не понял какой смысл привязываться к express и шаблонизаторам? Не дает ли больше контроля над собственным приложением подход с использованием базовых модулей node.js как описано в этой [книжке](http://www.nodebeginner.ru)

Прежде всего интересует с точки зрения безопасности (в том числе "затруднение" ддос атаки), а не удобства и времени разработки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шаблонизаторы удобны тем, что разметка не пишется в коде. ПОмимо отделения логики от разметки, отпаданет необходимость экранирования всяких символов и кучи конкатенаций строк.

Что касается контроля. Node.js даёт вообще максимальный контроль за происходящем. Но, чем более низкоуровневые инструменты ты используешь, тем больше придётся реализовать самому. Да, это даст максимальную гибкость в тех местах, которые нужны лично тебе. Но одновременно это значительно увеличит время разработки.

Далее, в плане безопасности. Вот стал ты делать что-то сам. Да, возможно, ты суперкрутой специалист в этой теме, сделаешь всё идеально и оно будет очень хорошо работать. Да, возможно. Но таких случаев единицы. Весьма вероятно, что ты что-то не учтёшь, сделаешь посредственно и, даже если удастся избежать явных косяков, можно просто насажать всяких дыр.

Плюс популярных модулей в том, что они широко используются и можно рассчитывать, что раз их выбрали, то они достаточно качественные, чтобы этого заслужить. Кроме того, можно рассчитывать на исправление ошибок в них, если такие обнаружатся. Минус же в том, что если вдруг выясняется какая-либо дыра, то все, кто использует этот модуль становятся уязвимы. Вполне возможно, что никого твой сайтик особо и не интересовал, чтобы искать в нём дыры, даже если их там много. Но вот опробовать нечто уже готовое на нём - почему бы нет.

В большинстве случаев быстрота разработки и достаточная надёжность перевешивают необходимость в излишней гибкости. Ну мало кто хочет себе признаться "я делаю хреновый сайт, на котором будет полтора человека и пофиг на все дыры, как-нибудь сам слеплю".

Хотя в целях обучения можно было бы попробовать написать нужную функциональность самому вместо использования готового модуля.