# Нужен ли мне фреймворк для законченного сайта?

Tags: framework

Совсем недавно дописал сайт(первый) и лишь после узнал про фреймворки. Стоит ли мне его устанавливать раз сайт закончен, дает ли он какую то дополнительную защиту для сайта или, может, повышает работоспособность?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446011/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Там нет ответа на мой вопрос. Там пишется про то, что возможно я при разработке могу оставить дыры в коде, но так как разработка уже закончена, то эти дыры в моем случае, как я понимаю фреймворк уже не найдет, ведь я им не пользовался при создании.

Comment: Не думаю, разве что только если у вас есть желание полностью переписать свой сайт с использованием новой технологии. А так это проще, удобнее, быстрее в процессе написания сайте, и иногда надежнее в последствии для уже написанного.